# For getstream.io, what is the best activity model for comments/likes on comments?

Tags: getstream-io

I need a little bit of help with GetStream.io activities.  I am implementing the usual timeline that one can see on LinkedIn or Facebook where a user can post an object.  The activity for this would be:

```
actor: 'user:john',
verb: 'post',
object: 'article:internal_id_of_article',
foreign_id: 'john_post_internal_id'
```

The activity is added to the user's feed.

If another user wants to add comment to the initial post, then I suppose the activity could be like this:

```
actor: 'user:jane',
verb: 'comment',
object: 'article:internal_id_of_article',
foreign_id: 'jane_comment_internal_id'
```

Is this the best way?  Then what about another user adding a comment to Jane's comment?  What is the best model so that I can eventually aggregate all these activities around the original post?  Is this where `target` would be used?

```
actor: 'user:victor',
verb: 'comment',
object: 'article:internal_id_of_article',
foreign_id: 'victor_comment_internal_id',
target: 'comment:jane_comment_internal_id'
```

The same could apply to liking the original post or the comment.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: which API client are you using?

Comment: I am using the PHP API client.  I am looking for guidance on the activity/feed model to use.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution. I'm looking to avoid re-implementing threaded comments from scratch if possible

Comment: I ended up implementing a comment as verb:comment, object: the activity that was commented (post or another comment) and then target is the "source" of the thread (post in my example).  I used target to contain the "source" only to make it easier to trace back to the first activity that started the thread when displaying it.  This way, I can retrieve the last 5 comments and still have a reference to the original post then display the post with the last 5 comments similar to Facebook's wall.  I am still in the process of implementing this so I am not 100% sure that this is the best approach.

Comment: What's the reason for not using [reactions](https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/docs/node/reactions_introduction/) to implement this? They are designed for this use case.